# Xamarin.Forms: Custom keyboard uses dot (.) instead of comma (,) for a german app. How to change that?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I had to use a custom entry to open a keyboard that even includes a decimal place with an numeric input type:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
            Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(169, 169, 169))) ;


            if (Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(true, true); // I know this is deprecated, but haven't had time to test the code without this line, I assume it will work without
                this.Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
            }

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(194, 213, 231));
            else
                Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(194, 213, 231), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
```

However, this only gives me a dot as a decimal place, but the app itself is german. So i need to display a comma instead of a dot. But the comma is greyed out.

How do I get ther?

Comment: If you change the phone's language to German, does it use comma? If that works, then there should be some android documentation about how to override phone's language/culture setttings.

Comment: the language is german ...

Comment: ok. Somehow you need to tell android the locale, in order to get comma. Look for a call similar to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener#getInstance(java.util.Locale)

Comment: Re deprecated: you can’t simply remove a deprecated call. Look at doc more closely, it tells you to instead make a different call, getInstance, which I hopefully link to above.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `Keyboard` property in xaml instead of custom renderer.

```
  <local:MyEntry Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Entry" />
```

[image]

Comment: Does that let them specify the locale?  Their goal is to have the European decimal separator character, a comma, instead of English dot. 55.1234567 => 55,1234567

Comment: As i know, the kaybord of German should be comma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator I am not sure this caused by the device or not.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  The comma seen in your answer.  Did you see that on the device's (or emulator's) numeric keyboard?  Was your device set to a European country or language that uses comma as decimal separator?  If you change device to US or England, does the keyboard change to show dot instead?

Comment: Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/vQSzWv1 The comma works with German. And the dot is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and showing that. I wasn't sure from the value in your answer, whether that comma was "thousands separator" (every three digits), or "decimal separator". Puzzling that whatever Jay first attempted, didn't result in the same UI.